# how can i count specific field multi rows of mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

how can I count Mysql Field Rows?

For example I have table called `student_attendance` where we have 4 fields: `absent`, `present`, `holiday`, `leave`.

There is list of 10+ students, each student value will go to its own field, like if for one student we selected absent, 1 value will go to absent field and if someone select present, 1 value will go to present field.

Now what i want is

Each time attendance take, new row insert in `student_attendance` table for the student.

So if there are 10 Rows in student_attendance table, how can i + all of them

Like if there are 10 rows of present field, 3 rows are empty and 7 rows have 1 value, how can i count it so that the total value of specific field 1+1+1+1+1+1+1 can comes in php so it show 7 ?

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? The thing you're looking for is called an *aggregate function*. Did you know this term before? If not, go look it up.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT SUM(present) AS presence_days
    FROM student_attendance
```

This will result:

```
+---------------+
| presence_days |
+---------------+
| 7             |
|               |
+---------------+
```

Example SQL ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e0a2/1)):

Comment: @hakre Thank you for your addition, it is really useful especially the Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from table_name where present_field=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(absent), SUM(present), SUM(holiday), SUM(leave) 
FROM student_attendance 
GROUP BY sudentId;
```